# If $E[(X \wedge b) \vee a] = E[(Y \wedge b) \vee a]$ all $a\leq b$ is $X =^d Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X,Y \in L^1$ and $E[(X \wedge b) \vee a] = E[(Y \wedge b) \vee a]$ for all $a\leq b$ do we necessarily have $X =^d Y$?

Taking $a=0$ the integrands are positive so we may use fubini to find

$$\int_0^\infty P[X^+ \wedge b\geq t]\,dt = \int_0^\infty P[X^+\geq, b \geq t]\,dt = \int_0^b P[X \geq t]\,dt$$
and similarly for $Y$, so that
$$
\int_0^b P[X \geq t]\,dt = \int_0^b P[Y \geq t]\,dt
$$
and differentiation yields $P[X\geq t] = P[Y \geq t]$ for all $t \geq 0$. Thus $X^+ =^d Y^+$. Similarly, $X^- =^d Y^-$. Can we somehow go further to find $X =^d Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you outlined, the statement that $X^- =^d Y^-$ means that 
$$P[X \leq s] = P[Y \leq s]$$
for all $s \leq 0$.

So we want to show: $X =^d Y$, i.e. $P[X \leq u] = P[Y \leq u]$ for $u \in \mathbb{R}$.  If $u \leq 0$ we are done by the above result.  Suppose instead that $u > 0$. Then

$$P[X \leq u] = 1 - P[X > u] = 1 - P[Y > u] = P[Y \leq u]$$

Here we used that $P[X > u] = P[Y > u]$ is implied by your first relationship: $P[X \geq u] = P[Y \geq u]$.

Comment: So simple I don't know how I missed it!